# What does the English word "for" exactly mean in "for" loops?

Tags: terminology, loops

English is not my first language, but since the keywords in programming languages are English words, I usually find it easy to read source code as English sentences:

- `if (x > 10) f();` => "If variable `x` is greater than `10`, then call function `f`."
- `while (i < 10) ++i;` => "While variable `i` is less than `10`, increase `i` by `1`."

But how a `for` loop is supposed to be read?

- `for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) f(i);` => ???

I mean, I know what a `for` loop is and how it works. My problem is only that I don't know what the English word "for" exactly means in `for` loops.

Comment: It is code. It isn't English. So... they don't directly compare. Don't try to find a direct meaning. The creators of a language had a limited vocabulary to choose from and went for terse.

Comment: You may read it as `for each`. So it would become `for each i, till i is less than 10, perform the following steps`.

Comment: @Oded OK, but why do you think they chose *this* word, and not another? OK, it's short, but I don't think this explains it.

Comment: @kol `for each i` pretty much explains everything.

Comment: It is confusing in C, and the keyword is there for historical reasons. In languages like Algol it reads much more naturally: "for an index variable blah-blah-blah in range blah-blah-blah do blah-blah-blah". In C it can be "for nothing do unconditionally something" which is confusing indeed.

Comment: "For each of my customers an email must be sent" I think Yoda was an ancient programming guru

Comment: @SK-logic "for nothing do unconditionally something" - Stroustrup wrote in his C++ book that `for (;;)` can be read as "forever".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For this particular case, it would be something like:

"For every i starting from 0 up to (but not including) 10, do f(i)"

It would have to be worded a bit differently if the numbers were doubles or the looping conditions were more complicated, but you shouldn't really worry if you can't find a really natural sounding translation to English because programming languages are only *based* on natural languages, or mathematical notation: `for i = 1,... 10` is something you write in math, which is much older than programming.

Comment: +1 for the math reference. in math you define a function `for` values in a domain. the part between the parentheses is the domain of the function defined between the braces. an empty `for` has an infinite domain, thus running indefinitely.

Comment: @devnull I like the domain explanation as an answer

Answer (score 12):

It's a lot more confusing because you've written out a C-style FOR loop, which isn't really a FOR loop; it's a WHILE loop with weird syntax.  The FOR loop was defined by ALGOL. Pascal and BASIC picked up the concept; C, unfortunately, borrowed the name but not the semantics.  (The best indication of this is to look at the `for (;;)` construct; it's not possible to define a true FOR loop that has no range to iterate over.)

The idea is that you define a range of elements, and an operation to perform **for** each element.  For example, in Pascal you would write your example loop as:

```
for i := 0 to 9 do
   f(i);
```

In BASIC it's similar:

```
for i = 0 to 9
   f(i)
next i
```

This is a lot more readable: *for each element `i` from 0 to 9, do something with the value.*  Note that there is no loop-ending condition involving `i` being `< 10`; instead, the last value of the range (9) is specified.

Answer (score 1):

For loops in C/C++ are very flexible, and as such, they don't translate directly to English very well.  The idea behind the for loop is iteration, and thus you would start out describing a simple initializer/condition/increment expression list with `for each value of i`.

This is my flexible, very verbose English representation of your for loop expressions:

`for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`

> For each value of i (initially 0), and while i is less than 10, iterate by incrementing i.

This representation allows you to adapt to more complicated expressions, such as:

```
int count = 10;
for (i = 0, j = count - 1; i < count; i++, j--) { //... }
```

> For each value of i (initially 0) and j (initially `count - 1`), and while i is less than `count`, iterate by incrementing i and decrementing j.

Or even:

```
vector<T> v;
for(vector<T>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it) { //... }
```

> For each value of `it` (initially the first element of v), and while `it` is not the last element of v, iterate by incrementing `it` to the next element of v.

Comment: +1 Thank you, very clear explanations. I especially like the way you use the word "initially".

Answer (score 0):

In English we use `for` in contexts like "This is for children under 6 year of age".  The `for` statement was adapted in structured programming in this context.

Read `for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) f(i);` as `for (; i < 10;) f(i);` and it might be clearer.  The for statement has three parameters:  initialization, condition, update. In some languages, the parameters can be lists.

For make the looping conditions clearer than the equivalent `while loop`.  If the body is long the increment may not be obvious.

```
 i = 0;
 while ( i < 10 ) {
     f(i);
     i++;
 }
```

In the following version the increment is misplaced.  The `for` construct doesn't allow the increment (update) to be misplaced in this manner.

```
 i = 0;
 while ( i < 10 ) {
     i++;
     f(i);
 }
```

Some languages provide a `for each` statement which is used to iterate over sets.

Answer (score -2):

Meriam Webster definition

For - "used to indicate ... something is going to or toward "

so your statement is i (starting at 0) going to 9.

Comment: That is the meanng in a sentence such as "I bought this book _for_ my sister". In this phrase, _for_ is indeed used to indidcate that the book is going to(ward) my sister. There is no range here, certainly no loop. I don't think it is this meaning that is referred to in programming languages.

Comment: The OP was looking at how the code statement could be interpreted.  Most of the answers were you can't.  I provided an alternative, a way it could be(loosely).

Comment: I think the question was meaning to ask "Why is this word used", or "how should the word be interpretted so that it is consistant with English". You gave a literal interprettation that didn't answer the intent of the question.